# api/values 404 not found localhost - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am perplexed as to why my Web API straight out of the box is not working locally.  I have created a new Web Api in Visual Studio 2017 .NET core, here is the controller:

```
namespace WebAPICore.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "Hello", "Hello 2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I am running via IIS as `webapicore.local/` so I am trying `webapicore.local/api/values` in the browser and I am getting a `404`!  It is also not working with Postman:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            <!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} 
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} 
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
..............
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are running in IIS then there might be an application name. So it could be webapicore.local/application/api/values

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen `webapicore.local/`, but if that is not necessary for your project, look in the autogenerated Properties/launchSettings.json file. Mine looks like this after creating a new web application project:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59313",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After launching with IIS navigate to https://localhost:59313/api/values, and it should work right out of the box.

Again though, if webapicore.local/ is necessary for your project this may not be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the same route but using the default port number 5000: `webapicore.local:5000/api/values`. This is assuming you haven't overridden the default application url in `launchSettings.json`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I feel a bit of an idiot, as I have I have just spoke to someone and they said you can't run a `.NET Core` web API directly from IIS, you need to publish the app, then install ASP.NET Core hosting bundle for Windows, then point IIS to the `publish` folder.  Now everything works as expected!  See more here: https://medium.com/tengweisong/deploy-and-host-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api-app-on-iis-e9f3b14bf47f